# jquery validation show error message only after user leaves field (leaves the field)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery validation on a beta sign up form, like this:-

```
$('#beta_signup_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true 
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span"

});
```

I only want to error element to show up when the user leaves the "name" field and when the user leaves the "email" field.

This seems to be a straightforward config issue but I am having trouble finding the right way to do it. How can do I specify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this options:

```
$('#beta_signup_form').validate({
    rules: {

    },
    focusCleanup: true,
    onkeyup: false,
```